# How to filter object with array inside?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to filter everything inside 'items' with 'name': "", without losing structure and values of fieldLabel and placeholder. Below is my current object:

```
result: {
    "fieldLabel": "foo",
    "placeholder": "foo",
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "foobar"
        },
        
            "name": ""
        },
        {
            "name": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the object to look like this after filtering:

```
result: {
   "fieldLabel": "foo",
   "placeholder": "foo",
   ​"items": [
       ​{
           ​"name": "foobar"
       ​},       ​       ​       ​
   ​]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have a reference to the original object first.

```js
const results = {
    "fieldLabel": "foo",
    "placeholder": "foo",
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "foobar"
        },
        {
            "name": ""
        },
        {
            "name": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Create a new object from the reference. Use [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax for copying object. Then [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method for filtering

```js
const newObject = {
  ...results,
  items: results.items.filter(item => item.name)
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the nested `items` array that have truthy `name` properties.

```js
const result= {
  "fieldLabel": "foo",
  "placeholder": "foo",
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "foobar"
    },
    {
      "name": ""
    },
    {
      "name": ""
    }
  ]
};

result.items = result.items.filter(({ name }) => name);

console.log(result);
```

If you need to do this using an immutable pattern then shallow copy the object and nested properties that you are updating.

```js
const result= {
  "fieldLabel": "foo",
  "placeholder": "foo",
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "foobar"
    },
    {
      "name": ""
    },
    {
      "name": ""
    }
  ]
};

const newresult = {
  ...result,
  items: result.items.filter(({ name }) => name)
};

console.log(newresult);
console.log(result === newresult); // false since new object
```

Comment: Thanks, using the spread syntax was a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Filter `YOUROBJ.items` to keep all entries where property name has a value that is not null/undefined/false

```
res.items = res.items.filter(e => e.name);
```

```js
const obj = {
    "fieldLabel": "foo",
    "placeholder": "foo",
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "foobar"
        },
        {
            "name": ""
        },
        {
            "name": ""
        }
    ]
}

const res = Object.assign({}, obj); // copy object to not mutate the original one
res.items = res.items.filter(e => e.name); // filter array "items" to just keep items with property name
console.log(res);
```